# fetch div data from DOM which starts from a specific id name

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

I am trying to fetch html div data, Which id starts from a specific name or string.

For example, Suppose i have this html data:-

```
<html>
  <div id="post_message_1">
      somecontent1
  </div>
 <div id="post_message_2">
      somecontent2
  </div>
    <div id="post_message_3">
      somecontent3
  </div>
 </html>
```

For this I tried curl.

```
        <?php
        function file_get_contents_curl($url)
        {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
        }


        $html = file_get_contents_curl("myUrl");
        $fh = fopen("test.html", 'w'); // we create the file, notice the 'w'. This is to be able to write to the file once.
        //writing response in newly created file
        fwrite($fh, $html); // here we write the data to the file.
        fclose($fh);                    
        ?>
```

If I use

```
  $select=  $doc->getElementById("post_message_");
```

Then it's not returning data, because its searching for this id in DOM, But in html div id only starts from this string. It may be post_message_1 or post_message_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd turn the output of `file_get_contents_curl` into
[SimpleXmlElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object and I'd use one of the functions of [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)

You can do this for example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
  <div id="post_message_1">
      somecontent1
  </div>
 <div id="post_message_2">
      somecontent2
  </div>
    <div id="post_message_3">
      somecontent3
  </div>
 </html>
HTML;

$dom = new SimpleXMLElement($html);

var_dump($dom->xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]'));
```

**UPDATE**

In your case you should do something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents_curl($url));

$sxml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

var_dump($sxml->xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]'));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion, but when i am using xpath then i am getting this error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' ", you can understand the HTML which i give, Is just for demo purpose.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot convert the html output of `file_get_contents_curl` to the php object simplexmlElement? I mean if you can take advantage of `SimpleXMLElement` it'll be very easy to you to do absolutely whatever you need

Comment: Yes, And lots of warning also showing like "PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &nbsp;  English</option><option value="78" class="fjdpth2" >&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; in /var/www/index.php on line 1"

Comment: It's ok bro, With your help i solved this problem, i posted the answer, You can also look on that.

Comment: I need some improvement in my code, can you help me? suppose if this div has test, Image and links, So i need to fetch only image and links not text. How i can do that?

Comment: Maybe something like this `var_dump($dom->xpath('//div[contains(text(), "") and .//img and .//a and starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]'));` and don't hesitate to look into [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) it really has all you need

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Its all most working, It's removes the texts, But not all text, Its not removing this text "string(80) "
 Quote:
 
       
     Originally Posted by shapey  
    
     
 "
" can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably iterate on all divs and use a regex on their id to get those I need.

I don't think there is a cleaner way to do it, unless you can edit the html page code and add classes to your divs containing messages.

Comment: I am fetching another website data so i cant add a class in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

brining a sledge hammer here but I have never been able to get patterns like this to work in PHP - but regex will work ->

```
$subject = $html;
$pattern = '/id\=\"post_message_\d+\"\>(?<match>.*)<\/div\>/isUg';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

var_dump(trim($matches['match']));
```

Regex explanation:

```
id\=\"post_message_\d+\"\>(?<matches>.*)<\/div\>/isU
id matches the characters id literally (case insensitive)
\= matches the character = literally
\" matches the character " literally
post_message_ matches the characters post_message_ literally (case insensitive)
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\" matches the character " literally
\> matches the character > literally
(?<matches>.*) Named capturing group matches
.* matches any character
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
< matches the characters < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
div matches the characters div literally (case insensitive)
\> matches the character > literally
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
U modifier: Ungreedy. The match becomes lazy by default. Now a ? following a quantifier makes it greedy
```

Comment: It's giving me only first div data. May be some modification needed.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, Its working fine. May be this code will help someone. And thanks to @smarber   his patterns help me to solve this.

```
    <?php
        function file_get_contents_curl($url)
        {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
        }


        $html = file_get_contents_curl("myUrl");
        $dom    = new DOMDocument();
   $result = $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
      $nodes = $finder->query('//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]');

       $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
   foreach ($nodes as $node) 
   {
$tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
   }

       $innerHTML = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
        $fh = fopen("test.html", 'w'); // we create the file, notice the 'w'. This is to be able to write to the file once.
        //writing response in newly created file
        fwrite($fh, $innerHTML); // here we write the data to the file.
        fclose($fh);                    
        ?>
```